# Https to another site

Tags: iis, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

I have a domain https://www.example.com (HTTPS) which is now pointing to another IP (for this example thats 1.2.3.4).

1.2.3.4 also has other domains within IIS's directory for that particular site.

When i navigate to www.example.com all is fine but as soon as i add https to it i get a cert error.

How could i avoid the cert error from showing up? I have a rule set for canonical to point to the correct address?

Comment: What exactly is the certificate error? And what URL?

Answer (score 0):

Its not surprising that http://www.example.com does not produce a cert error as there is no certificate involved with that call.  When you get the certificate error, you could look deeper into the error message that it provides.  I'm guessing there is a mismatch between www.example.com and the certificate.